# Command to get the list of databases in sqlite

Tags: xcode, sqlite

what is the command to  get the list of sqlite databases created so far in terminal.
i googled it but all i could get is .schema and .table commands which are not working after the terminal is reopened.

Answer (score 0):

`.databases` should do what you want.

Comment: yes, i am getting a list but only two databases are showing up.'main' and 'temp'.i created one database chandu.db yesterday and its not showing up.

Comment: i can see the database in '/users/username/' directory.So is there any other way i could access it?

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is no way to know how many db u have in some directory ...

u can use `.databases`in an opened database to know all *attached* databses to your database + the main one .

so that u get just 2 DBs ..

regards